# Bayesian model comparison with systematic error

Tags: self-study, bayesian, inference, measurement-error

> Two parameters $(x,y)$ were measured for 3 different objects, wielding the following results: $$\{ (x,y) \}= \{ (1,3), (3,5), (5,9) \}$$ Knowing that the error in the estimation of the values $y$ is described by a normal probability distribution: $p(y|x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi}} exp \left ( - \frac{(y-f(x))^2}{2} \right )$,
> where $f(x)$ represents the expected value for $y$, which can be calculated two in different models:
>
> - Model 1: $f_1(x)=2 x$
> - Model 2: $f_2 (x,\theta)= x + \theta$
>
> where $\theta$ is assumed to be an unknown parameter that can vary between $[1,5]$. Calculate the probability associated with each model and determine which is more likely. Then, consider the there is a systematic error associated with the estimation of $y$ that can reach a maximum amplitude of $10%$. Assuming the prior distribution for this error is uniform, explain how the probabilities for each model would change.

The first part of the exercise, I understand.
In this scenario, $p(y|x)$ is essentially the likelihood probability distribution for $y$, then, in both models, and since we know the measurements are independent from each other, I can determine the probability associated with each model by computing the "total" likelihood, that is, the product of the individual likelihoods:

$$p(M_i)= \prod_{D} \frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi}} exp \left ( - \frac{(y-f_i(x))^2}{2} \right )$$

for model 1 and, for model 2, since there is an extra unknown parameter, $\theta$, the final probability is found by marginalizing the "total likelihood" described above over this variable (in practice, by integrating it over all possible values of $\theta$).

What I don't understand is how we then take into account the existence of the error in $y$. My first thought  was to consider the systematic error as a new parameter which can vary between $0$ and $10%$, and marginalize each of this parameter as well, but I really don't know if this is correct. Does anyone know how this could be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your intuition is correct. From the problem description, I interpreted the systematic error $y_{sys}$ as being an unknown parameter that would be contributing additively to the measurements of $y$, but which is external to the models that we're trying to compare, and is the same between measurements, such that the likelihood function is changed to:

$$
P(y_j|x_j,M_{i},\theta,y_{sys}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y_j - f_i(x_j,\theta) - y_{sys})^2}{2}\right)
$$

Assuming that the measurements are independent, then the overall likelihood for the data $D$ could be expressed as

$$
P(D|M_{i},\theta,y_{sys})=\prod_j P(y_j|x_j,M_i,\theta,y_{sys})
$$

Then we will need to integrate out both $\theta$ and $y_{sys}$ as nuisance parameters to obtain the likelihood of the data for each of the models.
$$
P(D|M_{i}) = \int d\theta dy_{sys} P(D|M_{i},\theta,y_{sys}) P(\theta) P(y_{sys})
$$
The $\theta$ parameter has a uniform prior in a range between 1 to 5 as stated in the problem. $y_{sys}$ also has a uniform prior, but either in the range of -10 to 10 or 0 to 10 depending how you interpret the word "amplitude".

Then, by Bayes theorem, we can express the probability of each model $M_{i}$ in terms of our prior probabilities for the two models, and the likelihood ratio for the two models given the data:
$$
P(M_{i}|D) = \frac{P(M_{i})P(D|M_{i})}{P(M_{1})P(D|M_{1}) + P(M_{2})P(D|M_{2})}
$$
The problem statement does not specify what priors we should use for each of the two models that we're comparing, so we could put them on equal footing by specifying $P(M_{i}) = 1/2$.

Comment: thank you, that was very helpful!